# Angular CustomElements are destroyed when using Route Reuse Strategy to re-attach components

Tags: angular, view, routes, element, destroy

We use a tabbed-approach to allow navigating between multiple views without reloading each view entirely on tab-activation. to accomplish this, we use a route-reuse-strategy. when I use a customElement in one of the views, the customElement is rendered correctly only on first navigation to this view. navigating somewhere else and then going back to the previous view makes the customElement disappear completely. see this [Stackblitz-sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/route-reuse-strategy-xvdeub).

what am I doing wrong? I read that there are some issues in the current route-reuse-implementation according to this post: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27290
is there any fix? i can't believe that this scenario so unlikely that only three people encountered it

The customElement should remain visible upon activating the view regardless of order of navigation.